# Extracting pieces from URL in python

Tags: python, urllib2

I am iterating over multiple URLs in a csv file; the URLs have the next structure:

```
http://www.parool.nl/parool/nl/4024/AMSTERDAM-CENTRUM/article/detail/3751723/2014/09/21
http://www.parool.nl/parool/nl/5/POLITIEK/article/detail/3751624/2014/09/20/VVD-wil-  boete-van-250-euro-voor-het-naroepen-van-vrouwen.dhtml
```

etc.,

I need to get the article category (after the 4th slash, "AMSTERDAM-CENTRUM" and "POLITIEK", in this case), and append them to a list.

I'm working with urllib2:

```
reader=CsvUnicodeReader(open("my.csv","r"))
for row in reader:
    url = row[0]
    req=urllib2.Request(url)
```

Is there a way to parse the URL?

Comment: For splitting an URL in it's segments (protocol, host, port, path, etc..) there's the [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module (`urllib.parse` for Python 3.x). But it looks like you're interested in a particular part of the path, so you'd probably need to use a regular expression as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) to split the URL into its components and reliably extract the path component, and then use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract the category part of the path you're interested in:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
import re


URLS = ["http://www.parool.nl/parool/nl/4024/AMSTERDAM-CENTRUM/article/detail/3751723/2014/09/21",
        "http://www.parool.nl/parool/nl/5/POLITIEK/article/detail/3751624/2014/09/20/VVD-wil-boete-van-250-euro-voor-het-naroepen-van-vrouwen.dhtml"]

pattern = re.compile("/parool/nl/\d*/(.*?)/article/detail/.*$")


for url in URLS:
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    match = pattern.match(parsed.path)
    if match:
        category = match.group(1)
        print category
```

Output:

```
AMSTERDAM-CENTRUM
POLITIEK
```

---

Notes on the regular expression:

- `\d*` matches any digit (0-9) zero to multiple times
- `/(.*?)/` matches any character zero to multiple times between two slashes, non-greedy, and creates a group for the part between the slashes

Answer (score 1):

If all URLs have similar structure you can simply use

```
url.rsplit('/')[6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need regular expression here.

```
>>> a=[]
>>> with open('in','r') as f:
...     r=csv.reader(f,delimiter='/')
...     for row in r:
...             a.append(row[6])
... 
>>> a
['AMSTERDAM-CENTRUM', 'POLITIEK']



>>> a=[]
>>> with open('in','r') as f:
...     r=csv.reader(f)
...     for row in r:
...             a.append(row[0].split('/')[6])
... 
>>> a
['AMSTERDAM-CENTRUM', 'POLITIEK']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can figure it out with [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)  module  and get the article category with its `path` method then with `split('/')` function we splite the path with '\' and access 5th field with index [4]  .

Demo :

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> your_url=['http://www.parool.nl/parool/nl/4024/AMSTERDAM-CENTRUM/article/detail/3751723/2014/09/21','http://www.parool.nl/parool/nl/5/POLITIEK/article/detail/3751624/2014/09/20/VVD-wil-  boete-van-250-euro-voor-het-naroepen-van-vrouwen.dhtml']
>>> [urlparse(ul).path.split('/')[4] for ul in your_url]
['AMSTERDAM-CENTRUM', 'POLITIEK']
```